# Modularize user management server, social feed server

Tags: mongodb, system

I plan to design a system with Dreamfactory as the user management server while a separate REST server for social feed. Dreamfactory will have its own MySQL database for storing user info while the social feed will use MongoDB.

Is this a good system design? I'm new to this as I'm using both open source platform for two different purposes; social feed and user management.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question without knowing requirements to the system. I was going to ask you why storing users in MySQL, but all the same I can ask why using MongoDB or product XXX ;)

There is no silver bullet in programming. Tool is chosen from requirements, not vice versa.

If you do not need to relate data, do not need transactions and does not care about data consistency at all, why go why relational databases? Solutions like AeroSpike or just Redis (yes, it can be persistent too) can give you much higher read/write rate.

Well, I suggest you go write a document, containing your system description, think of load this system is going to have. May be you will decide, that storing data in CSV files is ok for you (joking ;) )

Comment: Well, i need a back end engine to facilitate my mobile app. I could only resort to open source platforms like Dreamfactory. And my app has a functionality that allows user to post social feeds, something like Tumblr. Thus, i need to Dreamfactory as a usermanagement server and something like Pump.io as a social feed server.

Comment: @user4732629 I understand, but that is just a shallow description from which I can derive no recommendations at all, sorry.

Comment: No worries. I'm asking just a yes or no question, not looking for a recommendation.